# Matplotlib barchart color based on dictionary value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have searched for different SO questions in order to resolve my issue but none of them deal with the values from the dictionary.

I have a dictionary in the format of

```
{'ABCD': 10, 'MNO': 60, 'PQR': 70, 'XYZ': 100}
```

I have a variable with

```
Testing = 100
```

Am plotting a barchart for all the values in my dictionary

Now, I need different colors in the bar chart based on the values

If the values in the dictionary is <33% of testing value then red 
If the values in the dictionary is >=33% and <66% of testing value then yellow 
If the values in the dictionary is >=66% of testing value then blue

Ex:

```
'ABCD': 10
 Less than 33% of Target Value (100) - Red

'PQR': 70
 >=66% of Target value (100) - Blue
```

Hope someone helps me in finding out the solution

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Share what you have tried and where you are stuck. StackOverflow isn't a "write for me code editor". People behind are ready to help you with your code, not writing your code from scratch.